# How to compile a C program which includes the Winsock library on Mac OS X

Tags: c, linux, macos, sockets, winsock

I'm developing a portable client-server application in C. I'd like to be able to compile it in Mac OS X as well as in Linux and Windows. At this moment I'm working with Mac OS X. I'm trying to achieve this result by preprocessor directives as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#if defined WIN32
#include <winsock.h>
#else
#define closesocket close
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

int main(void) {

#if defined WIN32

    WSADATA wsaData;
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int iResult = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0){
        printf("Error at WSAStartup()\n");
        printf("A usable WinSock DLL cannot be found");
        return 0;
    }

#endif

    int Mysocket;

    //***MyCode***

    closesocket(Mysocket);

#if defined WIN32
    WSACleanup();
#endif

    return 0;

}
```

When it comes to compiling this code in Mac OS X the compiler cannot find "winsock.h". Of course the file and the libraries it points aren't present in Mac OS X. Anyway: shouldn't the preprocessor directives I used avoid this problem when I work with Mac OS X and Linux?
And if they don't, is there any way to develop such a program in a way that, once it's finished, it can be compiled on all the platforms I mentioned?

Comment: Is `WIN32` defined somewhere, like in a makefile or on the command line?

Comment: Use `#if defined(WIN32)` or `#ifdef WIN32` instead.